# How do I use both single and double quotes in a python string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going a little crazy trying out all combinations. I need a string variable whose value is set to: **r'" a very long string \r"'**
This long string is given across multiple lines. My code looks like this:

```
str = r'" a very 
      long 
      string \r"'
```

This is introducing "\n" in the str variable. I tried using this syntax """ ...""" too. But I get a syntax error. Can someone help me please ? I saw the other Qs on stackoverflow, they don't seem to match this requirement.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *multiple string literals*; as long as they are on the same logical line they'll be concatenated to one long string. You can extend the logical line with paretheses:

```
yourstr = (
    '" a very'
    'long '
    r'string \r"')
```

Note that I *mixed string literal types* here. The first two parts are normal string literals, the latter part is a raw string literal so you don't have to double the `\` in `\r`. If you really wanted to have a CR carriage return, omit the `r` prefix.

Demo:

```
>>> yourstr = (
...     '" a very'
...     'long '
...     r'string \r"')
>>> yourstr
'" a verylong string \\r"'
>>> print yourstr
" a verylong string \r"
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python compiler concatenates adjacent string literals. The trick is to tell it that it should be considered a single line of code.

```
S = ('" a very '
     'long '
     r'string \r"')
```